# how do I reset my health on skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I used console commands to have a lot of health, now I can't seem to reset it, I am almost invincible and it takes the fun out of the game please help

Comment: Not a duplicate. It's not the maximum health he's talking about.

Comment: Try "player.setav health #" (without quotation marks). Just set it to your maximum health. I hope this works :)

Comment: Still doesn't work I still have about 2000 health

Comment: I used the command player.modav health

Comment: You need to replace the # by the amount of health you want to have. Skyrim doesnt know what Health you were previously on because you've overwritten it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you used `player.modav` to cheat your health higher than normal, you can use the same command with a negative value to get it back down.

`player.modav health -1000` will lower your max health by 1000, for example.